# How to import two or more modules with the same name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, import

Here's the code which is causing me trouble:

```
import time
from time import time

time.sleep(1)
start=time()
input=raw_input(' ')
end=time()
time.sleep(1)

print (start - end)
```

The issues are the following two imports with the same name as `time`:

```
import time

from time import time
```

How can I access both of these modules in my code? I need to use both the following lines in my code:

```
lines time()
and time.sleep()
```

But once imported, second module overrides the first one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How to import two or more modules with the same name?

Python provides the way to import modules with an alias. For example in your case, you may do:

```
import time as t   # access "time" as "t"
from time import time as tt  # access "time.time" as "tt"
```

In order to use, just use the alias as:

```
t.sleep(1)   # equivalent to "time.sleep(1)"

start = tt()  # equivalent to "start = time.time()"
```

In fact you can also store the imported modules in variables and aceess it later:

```
import time
t = time

from time import time
tt = time
```

But why to do this when Python already supports aliases?

---

### Better approach for your scenario

My above answer is aimed at any such general scenario. Though for your's specific problem [*Turksarama's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159952/2063361) makes more sense , because `time.sleep` and `time.time` belongs to same module. Just import them and use them together. For example:

```
import time

time.sleep(10)
time.time()
```

OR,

```
from time import time, sleep

sleep(10)
time()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would import sleep seperately.

```
from time import time, sleep

sleep(1)
start=time()
# changed input to inp, input is already an inbuilt function so you shouldn't shadow it.
inp=raw_input(' ')
# you had end = sleep(1) here, but sleep returns None
sleep(1)
end=time()

print (start - end)
```